# How to use HAML Language in .net pages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html, haml

I want to use HAML in .net, How to use HAML Language in .net pages

I want to use HAML in .net, How to use HAML Language in .net pages.Is HAML supports in all browsers? and also is there any full length video tutorials from scratch to end for haml for .net .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.[Look here for tips on writing a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: https://code.google.com/archive/p/nhaml/

Answer (score 0):

I am using Haml in rails app. So haml is not dependent on browsers, as it is just a replacement for html

for example :-

In html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <body>
       <div class= "some_class"></div>
    </body>
  </head>
</html>
```

the same code in haml is

```
%html
  %head
    %body
      .some_class
```

So here when u compare in haml you dont have to end the tags.
but indentation is very important in haml.

Reference :- http://haml.info/

well,i dont know wheather haml supports asp.net

Comment: Hi Krishna thanks for your valuable information but how to run haml in local, i tried through command prompt but its not working

Comment: and please send me your mail id to keep in touch with you if any help requires mahadevareddy.e@gmail.com